# Що таке "кардонка"?

Tags: значення-слів

У "Ганусі" Мізерницького:

> Похмурий ранок, Гануся умощується в бричку їхати на станцію. З **кардонки** виглядає пір’я шуліки. Гануся трохи сумна й задумлива.

Словники СУМ-11 і -20, Грінченка, r2u такого слова не знаходять, етимолоґічний словник у 6-ти томах так само не допоміг.

Що це за таке слово?

Comment: Просто для контексту: http://shron2.chtyvo.org.ua/Chervonyi_shliakh/1926_N07-08.pdf#page=79.

Comment: @Sasha дякую)))

Answer (score 7):

Схоже це "картонка" - коробка з картону або фанери http://sum.in.ua/s/kartonka

> **КАРТО́НКА**, Коробка з картону для легких речей.
>
> [Аліна:] То я вам привезла свою вінчальну сукню показати... (Розкриває картонку) (Сава Голованівський, Драми, 1958, 9).

"Кардонка" з тим самим значенням є у [білоруських](https://www.skarnik.by/tsbm/32018) та [російських](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/831854/%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%A0%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%9D%D0%9A%D0%90) словниках (як діалектна або розмовна).

Comment: Та ось буває по-різному: https://unc.ua/uk/pochitat/namitka-figuruje-shche-z-chasiv-kijivskoji-rusi-244 Як на мене, ви спрощуєте (і це через налаштування пошуку, думаю)).

Comment: Головний убір бачив у російських словниках, але не бачив в українських.

Comment: @P.Vowk, спочатку я був думав, що Ви маєте рацію, а Artemix помиляється. Що це головний убір. Тим більше, що до цього в тексті з'являється слово _кар**т**онка_ саме через -т- (мовляв, навряд чи один і той самий автор писав би одне й те саме слово то через -т-, то через -д-). Думав, що автор хоче підкреслити мінливість настрою героїні: (1) спочатку вона просить застрелити птаха, що полює на мишу, (2) потім вона б'є мишу та жаліє й намагається пораненого птаха, (3) потім вона робить з пір'їни мертвого птаха прикрасу до капелюха.

Comment: Але можлива й інша інтерпретація, на боці Artemix. На с. 78 Ганнуся зробила з картонки кубло для пораненого птаха («з картонки вона будує кубло для пораненого бранця»), а на с. 79 (у Вашій цитаті) вона, взявши з собою тіло птаха й ту саму картонку, поїхала на станцію. Те, що _кар{т/д}онка_ першого разу написано через -т-, а другого — через -д-, несуттєво. Наразі я схиляюся саме до цієї версії, бо якщо тіло птаха значило для неї настільки багато, що вона взяла його в поїздку, навряд чи вона встромляла би перо в капелюх; імовірніше, з картонки виглядало саме тіло птаха.

Comment: @Sasha так проблема не в самій відповіді, а у спрощенні. Якби відповідь була така, як ви розписали в коментарях - я б мінімум поставив стрілочку вгору.

Comment: @Sasha гадаю, ваші коментарі заслуговують на окрему відповідь

Comment: @Yola я теж так гадаю.

Answer (score 1):

Гадаю, що кардонка - це [калька](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/831514) з російської мови. Адже там воно означає "коробка з картону або фанери для легких речей". А перед цим пише, що Гануся зробила для птаха кубло з картонки. І якщо ми заглянемо в [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/kartonka) з цим словом, то побачимо:

> КАРТО́НКА, и, жін. Коробка з картону для легких речей.

Не знаю чи це 100% правильна версія (бо все ж я не розумію чому спершу написано "картонка", а потім "кардонка), але гадаю, що в тексті йдеться саме про коробку з картона.